# (Typo3 / powermail) parsley js: add offset to focused field

Tags: jquery, typo3, parsley.js, typo3-8.x, powermail

Is there a way to add an offset to the focused field?

When I validate my powermail form and there is an error, the page automatically jumps to the first invalid field of it.

My problem is, that I'm using a fixed header, which coveres the invalid field.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: I also have the problem. I would be very happy about a solution.

Answer (score -1):

This is done in the JavaScript file of powermail. I'd copy that JS file, adapt it and integrate it via TypoScript.